# Adding variables in db_query for webform dynamic select

Tags: 6, webforms, database

I would like to populate a dynamic select option in page 2 of my webform based on the value of another select option in the previous page.
I would like to use a variable in db_query, and hence tried this. But it doesn't work. I am not sure where I went wrong. Kindly let me know how I could solve this problem.

```
$array = array();
$major = $form_values['submitted_tree']['choose_your_major'];
$sql = db_query("SELECT data FROM webform_submitted_data WHERE nid = 2133 and cid =23 and data = '%s'", $major);
while($row = db_fetch_object($sql)) {
    $array[] = $row->data; 
}
return $array;
```

Comment: Drupal 6 I guess ? Are you sure the `webform_submitted_data` table contains datas at this point ?

Comment: Yes Drupal 6. Here the "webform_submitted_data" query refers to info submitted via another form for company registrations. I am checking if the company's preferences for "majors recruiting" matches with that of the student's major selected and then display companies choices accordingly.